# fluid-fixed-fluid Layout using Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

but I've read a lot of others)

I'm trying to create a fluid-fixed-fluid layout for my portfolio site. I've tried a few different options online, but everyone I see either offers a fixed-fluid-fixed or a layout which has the two fluid columns off to the side.

I'd love to have a straight-forward 1024px with middle (content) section with two supporting fluid columns beside.

I don't have much code to provide, but I'll create some sort of example for go by.

Thanks in advance - I feel kind of dumb asking this, but I haven't had to think about web in a couple of years and now I feel way behind.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3"></div>
</div>

<div id="row-fixed">
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>

<div id="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of back in the day...over ten years ago when we saw lots of framesets. You could just give a frame width="*" and it would take up however much width was left on the page. I really wish today's CSS offered the same...but, it doesn't.

You could easily emulate the effect with js, css and html.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="sidebar pull-left">

     </div>
     <div class="sidebar pull-right">

     </div>
     <div class="main-content">

     </div>
</div>
```

JS: (Tested in Mac OSX - Chrome Version 29.0.1547.65) http://jsfiddle.net/mmME5/

```
function setSidebarWidth(){
    var container_width = $('.container').width();
    var main_content_width = $('.main-content').width();

    //init sidebars
    $('.sidebar').width((container_width - main_content_width)/2);

    return;
}

$(function(){
    //init at document ready
    setSidebarWidth();

    //resize listener
    $(window).resize(function(){
        setSidebarWidth();
    });
});
```

NOTE: You may need to use .outerWidth(true) in the js function depending if your divs have margin or not.

Then style up your heights, backgrounds, borders, etc... as you see fit.

Let me know if you have any luck.